# How to filter JSON data using Python?

Tags: python, json

How to convert JSON data from **input.json** to **output.json** using Python? In general, what data structures are used for filtering JSON data?

**File: input.json**

```
[
{
    "id":1,
    "a":22,
    "b":11
},
{
    "id":1,
    "e":44,
    "c":77,
    "f":55,
    "d":66
},
{
    "id":3,
    "b":11,
    "a":22
},
{
    "id":3,
    "d":44,
    "c":88
}
]
```

**File: output.json**

```
[
{
    "id":1,
    "a":22,
    "b":11,
    "e":44,
    "c":77,
    "f":55,
    "d":66
},
{
    "id":3,
    "b":11,
    "a":22,
    "d":44,
    "c":88
}
]
```

Any pointers would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you considered dictionaries? :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The idea is to:

- use [`json.load()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.load) to load the JSON content from file to a Python list
- regroup the data by the `id`, using [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) and `.update()` method
- use [`json.dump()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dump) to dump the result into the JSON file

Implementation:

```
import json
from collections import defaultdict

# read JSON data
with open("input.json") as input_file:
    old_data = json.load(input_file)

# regroup data
d = defaultdict(dict)
for item in old_data:
    d[item["id"]].update(item)

# write JSON data
with open("output.json", "w") as output_file:
    json.dump(list(d.values()), output_file, indent=4)
```

Now the `output.json` would contain:

```
[
    {
        "d": 66,
        "e": 44,
        "a": 22,
        "b": 11,
        "c": 77,
        "id": 1,
        "f": 55
    },
    {
        "b": 11,
        "id": 3,
        "d": 44,
        "c": 88,
        "a": 22
    }
]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
from collections import defaultdict

input_list=[{"id":1, ...}, {...}]

result_dict=defaultdict(dict)
for d in input_list:
    result_dict[d['id']].update(d)

output_list=result_dict.values()
```

`result_dict` is a [default dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) which uses a `dict` for every access without a available key. So we iterate through the input_list and update our result_dict with key equals `id` with the new values from the corresponding dictionary.

The output list is a transformation of the `result_dict` and uses only its values.

Use the [`json` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) to work directly with the json data.